# How to handle data changes and view updates when activity is in background

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have an App with 2 activities A -> B. From B the user can update data being displayed by A, so I want A to show fresh data when the user navigates back (actually not so simple, some network involved so data can be updated at any time).

The activities are listening to ddbb changes so the views can be updated when data changes. Problem is data can change while activities are in background, so I am not sure when and how i should listen for changes. I can think of two approaches:

1. Listen for changes during the whole Activity lifecycle (onCreate - onDestroy) and just update the views when the data changes. This will update views from background activities.
2. Listen for changes only when the Activity is being active or displayed (between onStart/onStop or onResume/onPause) and force a view update every time the activity comes to the foreground (since changes might have happened while activity wasn't listening).
3. Mixed approaches; keep the listeners the whole lifecycle but only update views when activity comes to foreground.

Im not sure which is the correct way to handle data observing while in background. 
Option 2 sounds more reasonable, but having to update the views when the activity comes to foreground may lead to UI lag right when the user starts interacting with the activity.
Option 1 will cause a lot of updates every time data is updated.

Thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose any of the three options that suits your particular use case.  Though I will say that the conventional use is with start/stop.  onStart says that the activity is visible to the user in some way (either fully or partially) and onStop says that the activity is definitely not visible.  So if you don't care to update the UI while the activity is not showing at all, use these lifecycle states.

You just may need to be prepared to capture data that you may have missed while the activity was stopped before it gets started again (for example, if the user pressed the home button, then came back to the activity via the task switcher.  So performing your query again and rebuilding the contents of views from scratch may be necessary.